# Array in generic List

Tags: c#, arrays, generic-list

I need to create a Generic List and keep the data in the `Array` class.
Array will be as much as I mentioned in the constructor method (I'm open to more practical solutions and ideas).

My problem is that I don't get int values when I print in the List, and I can't find out how to access that data one by one.

```
public class Demo
{
    public int GrupKodu { get; set; }
    public string GrupAd { get; set; }
    public int[] Notlar;

    public Demo(int GrupKodu, string GrupAd, int NotAdet , int[] a  )
    {
        this.GrupKodu = GrupKodu;
        this.GrupAd = GrupAd;
        this.Notlar = new int[NotAdet];
        this.Notlar = a;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Grup Kodu : {this.GrupKodu} Grup Adı : {this.GrupAd} Notlar : {Notlar}";
    }
}
```

I'm doing an invocation with data insertion and `for` loop.
I tried the same print operation with the `Foreach` loop, but the `Sonush` did not change.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Demo> DemoListe = new List<Demo>();
    DemoListe.Add(new Demo(101, "umt", 6, new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }));
    DemoListe.Add(new Demo(101, "umt", 2, new int[] { 1, 2,}));
    DemoListe.Add(new Demo(101, "umt", 3, new int[] { 1, 2, 3}));
    DemoListe.Add(new Demo(101, "umt", 7, new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7 }));
    DemoListe.Add(new Demo(101, "umt", 8, new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ,7,8}));

    foreach (Demo item in DemoListe)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < DemoListe.Count(); i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"GrupAd : {DemoListe[i].GrupAd}  GrupKod : {DemoListe[i].GrupKodu}  Notlar : {DemoListe[i].Notlar.ToArray<int>()}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `String.Join` in your `ToString` override like so:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"Grup Kodu : {this.GrupKodu} Grup Adı : {this.GrupAd} Notlar : {String.Join(", ", Notlar)}";
}
```

`String.Join` turns an enumerable into a string seperated by a seperator.

So if `Notlar = [1,2,3]`, `String.Join(", ", Notlar) = "1, 2, 3"`

Comment: Thanks Loocid.
If I want to trade with numbers in the Array, I can get access to it and perform mathematical operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply flatten the array using Join as per above answer or print the contents one by one:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    if (Notlar.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (int s in Notlar)
        {
            sb.Append(" ");
            sb.Append(s.ToString());
        }
    }

 return $"Grup Kodu : {this.GrupKodu} Grup Adı : {this.GrupAd} Notlar : {sb.ToString()}";
 }
```